# Are there any rewards for fully restoring Norende?

Tags: bravely-default

I know that in the demo you receive a play kit bonus for fully upgrading all of the shops in the village, but is there a similar reward for doing so in the full version of the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you fully rebuild Norende you have access to some pretty sweet items, with the village shopkeepers occasionally sending you some of their stock as a gift (sadly, never weapons or armor). But besides that, you only get an extra Party Chat scene. No extra gifts as far as I can recall.

Comment: I just finished Norende and can confirm that the is no bonus pack awarded for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

he is right there aren't any extra things you get after restoring Norende like in the demo version but when you restore some of the shops there to the max level some of the will sell the original outfit for the 4 caracters Agnes : The knights tunic Tiz : onion shirt ringabell: the melodist outfit and Edea's : Edeas garb and there's another option to buy called the plain tunic wich does the same thing for the same price except you can equip it to any of the character's and that's pretty much it.

Comment: Who is right? (Ignore this, I didn't have enough characters.)

Comment: @peper757 He's referring to the other answer.